# ZendFramework, Doctrine 2 ODM with mongoDB - Hydrator Error

Tags: zend-framework, mongodb, doctrine-odm

I'm using Zend Framework in combination with Doctrine 2 and mongoDB.
So far so good.

Now I'm rewriting my custom validation class in order to check if a username already exists in the database. (This code worked fine with ORM and MySQL, but not now with ODM and mongoDB).

So my custom validation class looks like this:

```
<?php

class Project_Validate_UsernameUnique extends Zend_Validate_Abstract {
const USERNAME_EXISTS = '';

protected $_messageTemplates = array (
    self::USERNAME_EXISTS => "'%value%' is taken. Please choose another username."
);

public function isValid($value) {
            // setting value for the form
            $this->_setValue($value);

            // get the document manager and repository              
            $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
            $dm = $front->getParam('bootstrap')->getResource('odm');
            $userRepository = $dm->getRepository('Entities\User');

            $user = $userRepository->findOneBy(array('username' => $value));        

            // if an user was found, return false
            if ($user) {
                    $this->_error(self::USERNAME_EXISTS);
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
     }
}
```

But I get this error here:

```
Warning:   file_put_contents(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/application/models/Hydrators/EntitiesUserHydrator.php) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/library/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Hydrator/HydratorFactory.php on line 343
```

I also tried findBy and without the array annotation (findByUsername or findOneByUsername), but still, either I get this error or somehow "nothing".
With ORM and MySQL it worked perfect, so where is the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your Hydrators folder writable by PHP?

Comment: Hey man! This was exactly the point! I had the main folder writable, but I forgot to add it also for the enclosed items! Thanks a lot! You made my day! =)

Comment: Thax a lot dude =). Though i dont have no idea why we're using it for!